# IE7 new Function returning object instead of function

Tags: javascript

What can cause this behavior in IE7? I can't reproduce this issue on jsfiddle...

```
var func=new Function('arg','return 2*2;');
alert(typeof func);
```

Returns object.

I'm totaly confused.

How to debug this issue? How to figure out why new Function is returning an object?

**UPDATE**

It shouldn't be that way right? Or I just don't understand something? To me it looks like Windows 8 bug.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mhyuab3mhj2yu59/ie7_windows8_bug.png

**UPDATE**

This is up to IE8, in IE9 it's gone.

Comment: Granted, it should be returning "function". But what is there to debug here?

Comment: can't you just create a function normally?

Comment: I don't have IE7, but i got `function` in the IE7 mode of IE9.

Comment: I get `function` in Chrome. It's a bizarre way to create a function though.

Comment: This alerts `"function"` for me (IE9 in IE7 mode). - @MrMisterMan This is the way to create a function from a string (i.e., dynamically).

Comment: Updated my main post, please take a look.

Comment: @Tomalak Every day's a school day. I've never seen a function created that way before.

Comment: I will post why i'm using this way of function creation. It's kinda advanced tehnique by John Resig if you know who is it. Just help me to find a solution for this. O_o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved via this solution:

```
var func=eval('(function(){return function(){ your code here }})()');
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't replicate this on my machine, and your right - it is wrong.  Anything which is `callable` should return `function` for the `typeof` operator according to the [EMCA specs](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.4.3).  If you want to test whether a given variable is a function in the face of this problem, you could use:

```
function isFunction(func){
    return  typeof func === 'function' ||
           (typeof func === 'object' && func instanceof Function); 
}
```

Comment: It shows that func is instance of Function, but it's type is object.

Comment: Yeah, so the second part of the return statement will pick that case up.  I'm guessing that it is still a function in that it can be executed and used like one.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mhyuab3mhj2yu59/ie7_windows8_bug.png it throws exception

Comment: Everything works as intended in Windows XP. Seems like a bug in Windows 8 after all.

Comment: Well I guess in that case, it probably makes more sense that it is of type `object` since it can't be used like that.  I guess if it's causing a problem (you could use `execScript` or `eval` to create the function, you can do this on the [global scope too](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/driscoll/archive/2009/09/08/eval-javascript-global-context)).  You may be able to redefine `Function` for IE7 to do just do wrap a call to that automatically too so you wouldn't need to change your code.

Comment: Yes you was right. I have done it via eval. And all errors disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

To extend [Mark Rhodes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10699692/887539) answer

```
function realType( t ) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(t).slice(8, -1);
};
```

---

```
var func=new Function('arg','return 2*2;');

alert( realType(func) ); // Function/Object
alert( realType([]) ); // Array
alert( typeof [] ) // object

alert( realType(new Date) ); // Date
alert( typeof (new Date) ); // object
```

Comment: realType(new Function('x,y','return x*y;')); -> "Object"

Comment: @Beck ok it was a long shot. Thanks for testing.. Sorry for not working :(